# Farming rebel controlled sectors?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Does it ever make sense to not run from the chasing rebels?

I often end up in the situation where my last couple jumps out of a sector are through rebel controlled locations.  The fights are tough, but I often destroy the ship instead of jumping away early.  The rewards are paltry, 1 fuel or ~50 scrap.

But the rewards are non-zero.  Has anyone successfully tried farming this?

Comment: "But the rewards are non-zero." A reward of 1 fuel is a reward of zero.

Comment: I guess it is zero but it would allow you to keep farming.

Comment: If you can reliably farm the rebel main fleet this way, then your ship is already so advanced that you most likely don't need the farm in the first place.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The rebel ships you encounter after the sector has been taken over are intentionally harder than you would experience normally.  They've got heavier shields and better weapons than other encounters in your current (or even usually your next) sector.

The rewards are also minimal at best.  Just enough to keep you running.

You are unlikely to profit from these encounters over the long run.  In fact, hanging around and fighting the pursuing rebels is usually a quick way to get a game over.

Comment: the rewards are always just one fuel, with the explanation that you don't have time to grab the rest of the loot.

Comment: I have received a reward of 53 and 55 scrap.  Though 1 fuel is much more common.

Comment: And if you get scrap, you get no fuel, so your farming time is limited.

Comment: I found that odds were pretty good I'd get a ship I couldn't penetrate the shields on, and then I'm using up missiles/bombs to damage it, which is no good.

Comment: I've only ever received fuel. I think the standard is to receive one fuel so you can jump on if you've run out of fuel.

Comment: If you encounter a "rebel cruiser" or something, it's one fuel.  Basically, it's the same type of encounter as if you get caught in the outer-region of the rebel fleet in sectors 1-7.  If you encounter a scout (and kill it before it jumps), a raider (attacking a station/civilian, you will also get the "there's no time" dialog option to jump away), or an automated drone, you get "normal" rewards.

Answer (score 3):

If a goal of your play-through is to get the highest possible score for "beacons visited," then it might make sense to visit some extra beacons where the rebel fleet is present before leaving a sector, if you're confident that your ship can stand up to the extra punishment.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't make sense to not run from them. The rewards are just 1 fuel as to be able to move to the next beacon.